# How to encode '+' sign in ajax url

Tags: php, ajax

After + sign my url sting is terminated please give solution.

Comment: have you tried applying urleconding methods on the url? Client side and/or server side?

Comment: What u r saying and How your + sign terminates url, write here your some code that have flaw ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this function:
encodeURIComponent("+")